# Android canvas co-ordinates?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm playing with android co-ordinates, and I'm wondering how they work, are they allocated to each pixel? or are they allocated in a different way?

Just wondering because I'm scaling my drawings and it seems like the co-ordinates are not scaled by pixel.

Any input would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your canvas draws onto the bitmap. If your bitmap is the same size as your screen then it will scale 1:1.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html